# how to convert string build from variables to an object

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
val = val.split(".");
//val[0] is name
//val[1] is John
```

I have to build object like this:
`{name: "John"}`

So I do:

```
filterArray = "'{'"+val[0]+"':'"+val[1]+"'}'";

var t = JSON.parse(filterArray);
```

And when I do `console.log(filterArray);`
I want to get: **Object { name: "John" }**

But can't do it the right why, please help :)

Comment: `var o = {};  o[val[0]] = val[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: In es6 you can do const o = {[val[0]]: val[1]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how that should be done

```
val = val.split(".");
// Declaring an empty object
obj = {};
// Assingning a dynamic key and its value form you variable
obj[val[0]] = val[1];
console.log(obj) // Object { name: "John" }
```

Comment: Though this is correct way, you should not answer basic questions like these. A comment is more than enough

Comment: No need for sorry. Just remember, soon you will get privilege to close a question. Use it instead of answering

Comment: Thank you for helping and Rajesh thank you for your basic answer.